# Search for substring in two columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, string, substring

I currently have a scope:

```
scope :named,->(query) do
  where("(first_name || last_name) ~* ?", Regexp.escape(query || "a default string to prevent Regexp.escape(nil) errors"))
end
```

This works, except for when first_name or last_name is nil. How do I find with these columns if one of the columns is nil?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like this:

```
scope :named,->(query) do
  where("first_name IS NOT NULL OR last_name IS NOT NULL AND (first_name || last_name) ~* ?", Regexp.escape(query || "a default string to prevent Regexp.escape(nil) errors"))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic scope to search for a name, it handles a search for 'first_name only', 'last_name only' or a search for full name.

If you split the query into an array, you can grab the first and last of the array and does not matter whether the query is one or two in length.

You could replace the split with your regex if needed

You could obviously expand on this (e.g. case insensitive, ordering), but gives the basic idea.

Also handles a nil query by defaulting to a empty string, if the strip fails.

```
scope :named,->(query) do
  query.strip! rescue query = ""
  query_words = query.split(' ')
  where(["first_name LIKE ? OR last_name LIKE ?", "#{query_words.first}%", "#{query_words.last}%"])
end
```

Hope this helps